# Storing large json strings in Oracle Db

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

We have a use case to store large json strings (about 10 kb +) in Oracle Db. What column data type is the most ideally suited for this? Clob or blob?

Comment: Quote from Oracle documentation: "Oracle recommends that you use BLOB, not CLOB storage." Find the **Considerations When Using LOB Storage for JSON Data** section here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adjsn/overview-of-storage-and-management-of-JSON-data.html#GUID-26AB85D2-3277-451B-BFAA-9DD45355FCC7 But, aside from that - if you are going to use JSON in the database, why are you still using Oracle 11g? I assume that tag didn't attach itself there. Oracle first added JSON support in 12.1, with many more features in more recent versions (12.2, 19, ...)

Answer (score 0):

**For Oracle 12.1 and higher**, as Mathguy mentioned, you should follow Oracle's advice and use BLOBs to store JSON data. Recent versions of Oracle have added many SQL/JSON features that seamlessly deal with JSON regardless of the data type, and BLOBs will avoid some character set issues.

**For Oracle 11.2 and lower**, you should use CLOBs to store JSON data. Since you don't have access to native JSON functionality, you will probably need to rely on regular string processing. And dealing with character data in CLOBs is much easier than dealing with character data in BLOBs. (However, if you use a library like [PL/JSON](https://github.com/pljson/pljson), then BLOBs might still work OK.)